# Немного о бубликах

Tags: словообразование

"Бублик" — слово с уменьшительным суффиксом. А была ли когда-нибудь полная(а не уменьшительная) форма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском - нет. Что, кстати, заставляет усомниться в правильности трактовки -ик как суффикса.
А в родственных - есть. В польском, например, и чешском есть созвучные слова со значением "пузырь".

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая трактовка встречается:
Заимствование из украинского, где бублик является уменьшительно-ласкательной формой от бубьлъ, производного от того же корня, что и бубен.